# How many miles to repack bearings or replace on recumbent

Tags: bearings, recumbent

I have a Sun EZ-1 Super Cruzer recumbent.  It is the low end bike.  It is beginning to be harder to pedal.  Got at least 5,000 miles on it and never bearings have never been repacked or replaced.  Wondering if it time.  Also where can I get parts?  Normally Sun only works through dealers.

Comment: Have you replaced the chain, chainrings, idler, and cassette? Recumbents have a very long chainline that often drags low to the ground. You could use the occasion to see how much resistance there is in the “bottom” bracket (pedal assembly) and the rear cassette.

Comment: The other side, the long chain is often 3x longer and so goes around 3x less often.  That's 3x less wear on the chain, but the normal amount of wear on the cassette and chainring.

Comment: I generally figure 10-20K miles for wheel and crank bearings, unless they are subjected to a lot of bad conditions (including power washing).

Answer (score 2):

Bearings need repacking and ball replacement when the wheel isn't running smoothly, or has crunchiness when rolling.

So it could be time to redo the bearings.  Depending on what system the wheels use, it could be as little as a $5 packet of bearings and 5c worth of grease.

Sealed bearings are even easier - if they feel bad/rattly/noisy, they need replacing.

Specific to your bike, there's probably dirt and wear all over, so fixing one thing might not restore it to original performance.  Consider giving the entire transmission a clean, check the chain for wear, check the tyre's air pressure and that there is no brake rub.